# HPUX logging ftp connection

Tags: ftp, syslog, hp-ux

Host is 11iV3.

I am trying to log ftp transfert outside syslog.log

in /etc/inetd.conf

```
 ftp          stream tcp6 nowait root /usr/lbin/ftpd     ftpd -u 022 -o -i -X
```

where

- -i/-o tell ftpd to log input/output
- -X tell ftpd to use syslogd facilities

in syslogd.conf

```
 mail.debug         /var/adm/syslog/mail.log
 *.info;mail.none;local5.none       /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log
 local5.*           /var/adm/syslog/t-LOCAL5.log
 mail.info          /var/adm/syslog/t-MAIL.log
 *.alert                    /dev/console
 *.alert                    root
 *.emerg                    *
```

log of ftp activities goes to xxferlog (as instructed by ftpd), but not to any user defined log.

How can i redirect ftp's log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

**Inetd**

1) you must log ftp/fptd traffic. in `/etc/inetd.conf` add following arguments

```
ftpd -l -v -o -i -W
```

where

- `-l` log traffic to syslog.log
- `-v` add verbosity
- `-i` log incomming files (to `/var/adm/syslog/xferlog`)
- `-o` log outgoing files (to `/var/adm/syslog/xferlog`)
- `-W` tell ftpd to use syslog's configuration

**syslog**

2) tell syslogd to catch ftpd's log

by default, syslogd will log ftpd's message to `/var/adm/syslog/syslog.log` and incomming/outgoing files to `/var/adm/syslog/xferlog`, if you want to keep them appart add/modify following lines to `/etc/syslog.conf`.

```
*.info;mail.none;local5.none    /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log
local5.debug             /var/adm/syslog/ftpd.log
```

where

- `local5.none` tell syslog not to log ftp(local5) traffic to `syslog.log`
- `local5.debug` log all activities (including delete) to `/var/adm/syslog/ftpd.log`

**side note**

If you do not care about file deletion, you may wish to use only -i/-o in `inetd.conf` and `/var/adm/syslog/xferlog` and not bother with all of the above, which give much verbosity not always usefull.