# syslog error, unknown priority name ""

Tags: syslog

I am editing syslog and want to log ppp to a log. I added the last two lines to do so, as recommended in the ppp configuration. It appears to log ppp but also other things, due to the `*` I guess. I also get the error in the title. Any idea what the logging lines should be?

```
# /etc/syslog.conf - Configuration file for syslogd

auth,authpriv.*     /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none  /var/log/messages
user.*          /var/log/user.log
local0.*        /var/log/switch.log
local1.*        /var/log/audit.log
*.emerg         *
local0.*        /dev/ttyS0
!ppp
*.*             /var/log/switch.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it short, `syslog.conf` is configured like this

```
 facility.priority /place/to/log
```

ppp's facility is daemon.
priority range from debug to panic.

your last line

```
 *.* /var/log/switch.log
```

will log any facility on any priority to switch.log. This likely result in a flood.

Try

```
  daemon.debug /var/log/daemon.log
```

note also that according to pppd(8) (man page for pppd), pppd can be told to log to specific file.

Edit:

1. you have to *guess* what is the facility, I did it more or less for [HPUX logging ftp connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164427/hpux-logging-ftp-connection) .
2. two or more programs can share the same facility, some post processing (e.g. `grep ppp`) on log file is required.

Comment: Thanks, i will try your answer, I had tried mine as I had seen it several places online even though it didn't make sense to me https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/ppp.html Will try similar for the chat program.

Comment: How do you know what facility something has? I am trying to find chats one. also if I use daemon for ppp it will log things like mstpd as well.

Comment: I read in a book to use local2.debug for chat and it does work, however I have no idea why or how I would find this information otherwise, very strange. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when using **logger** command from bash and incorrectly using the '-p' flag. [See its man page under 'FACILITIES AND LEVELS' for all allowed values](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html#FACILITIES_AND%20LEVELS).  My working command looks like:

```
logger -p cron.info -t "($0)[$$]" "I'm going to the cron log."
```